# How to print results of function with use of alert() ?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to print what my function returns with use of alert() but I somehow cannot do it. I so something like this :

`<a href="#" onclick="alert(' javascript:XORFunction('hello', 'patr') ')" />hello </a>`

I have also tried with `document.write` like this :

`document.write( javascript:XORFunction('hello', 'pat') );`

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: if it's just for debug purpose, look at firebug or the native browser consoles on Chrome or IE (press F12). You can use 'console.log(yourObject)' to display data in these consoles, or just type the command in the console and see the result ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need the "javascript:" part because it's already inside a javascript block.

`<a href="#" onclick="alert(XORFunction('hello', 'patr'))">hello </a>`